# How to change the log.dirs for Kafka on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache-kafka

I have installed Kafka on Ubuntu 14.04. By default the `log.dirs` was set to `/tmp/kafka-logs`. I ran the server and it was working fine. Then I shutdown the server using `kafka-server-stop.sh` and changed the `log.dirs` in the config file a new directory.

After than when I tried to start the kafka server, I get the following error:

```
[2016-06-08 18:24:45,206] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
    at kafka.log.Log$.parseTopicPartitionName(Log.scala:833)
    at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:138)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-06-08 18:24:45,208] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Answer (score 3):

Performed the following steps

1. Stop the Kafka servers
2. Copy the data from /tmp and into the new directory
3. Change the server.properties
4. Restart the Kafka servers.

It worked fine for me. Referred to [this post](http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/1576pfxhdm/how-to-move-kafka-data-to-other-directories)